How to make image with small app icon in Notification?
I made Notification like Chat app. And i want to make notification like Figure 1
I think Figure 1 not using Custom Notification. Because i tested android OS 12 (Galaxy 24) and
Android 12 changes the appearance and behavior of fully custom notification link
This is my code that made MessageStyle Notification
 private fun buildNotification(
        title: String,
        content: String,
        userName: String,
        createdAt: String,
        largeIcon: Bitmap
    ): Notification {
        val sender = Person.Builder()
            //.setIcon(IconCompat.createWithAdaptiveBitmap(largeIcon))
            .setName(userName)
            .setImportant(true)
            .build()

        val message = NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle.Message(
            content,
            System.currentTimeMillis(),
            sender
        )

        val style = NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle(sender)
            .addMessage(message)
            //.setGroupConversation(true)
            .setConversationTitle(userName)


        val builder = getConditionResult(targetVersion = Build.VERSION_CODES.O,
            moreThanTargetVersion = {
                NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
            },
            lessThanTargetVersion = {
                NotificationCompat.Builder(context)

            })
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_with_background)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setGroup(GROUP_NAME)
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
            .setContentText(content)
            .setContentTitle(userName)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setStyle(style)

        return builder.build()
    }

How to make image with small app icon in Notification???
